# Flutter: AlertDialog and TextButton with The named parameter 'enabled' isn't defined

Tags: flutter

I am using `AlertDialog` and want to enable or disable according to the condition. However, I get this underline error saying

`The named parameter 'enabled' isn't defined. Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'enabled'.`

```
  actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            enabled: false,
            child: Text('Approve'),
            onPressed: () async {
              print('hello');
            },
          ),
        ],
```

[image]

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: You can use StatefulBuilder wrap AlertDialog 
Step 2: call `setState(() => enable = true);` with your condition 
Step 3: In `onPressed` set

```
onPressed: enable
        ? () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          }
        : null),
```

code snippet

```
Future<void> _showMyDialog(bool enable) async {
    return showDialog<void>(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text('AlertDialog Title'),
              content: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: ListBody(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('This is a demo alert dialog.'),
                    Text('Would you like to approve of this message?'),
                    TextButton(
                      child: Text("enable Approve"),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() => enable = true);
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                    child: Text('Approve'),
                    onPressed: enable
                        ? () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          }
                        : null),
              ],
            );
          });
        });
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<void> _showMyDialog(bool enable) async {
    return showDialog<void>(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text('AlertDialog Title'),
              content: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: ListBody(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('This is a demo alert dialog.'),
                    Text('Would you like to approve of this message?'),
                    TextButton(
                      child: Text("enable Approve"),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() => enable = true);
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                    child: Text('Approve'),
                    onPressed: enable
                        ? () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          }
                        : null),
              ],
            );
          });
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _showMyDialog(false);
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, so I thought it was part of TextButton's direct property. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: `enabled` is a dynamic getter that returns `true` if `onPressed` or `onLongPress` are set to a non-null value, and returns `false` otherwise.

---

The answer can be found by investigating the `ButtonStyleButton`, which is the `Class` that `TextButton` extends, specifically:

```
/// Whether the button is enabled or disabled.
///
/// Buttons are disabled by default. To enable a button, set its [onPressed]
/// or [onLongPress] properties to a non-null value.
bool get enabled => onPressed != null || onLongPress != null;
```

The `TextButton` will be `enabled` if it has a `onLongPress` or a `onPressed` callback set to a non-null value.

That said, according to the scenario you specified, we could build the `TextButton` as follows:

```
bool _enabled = true;

Widget _buildTextButton() {
   return TextButton(
     child: Text('Approve'),
     onPressed: _enabled ? _onPressed() : null,
   );
)

void _toggleEnabled() {
   setState(() => _enabled = != _enabled);
}

void _onPressed() {
   print('pressed!');
}
```